# Find an initial condition for a give linear system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the linear system of equation

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\left( \begin{array}{cc} -1 & \frac{1}{\epsilon} \\
0 & -2 \end{array} \right)x
$$
Find an initial condition with $\Vert x(0) \Vert=1$ and $\Vert x(t) \Vert >\frac{C}{\epsilon}$ for any $0<t_1<t<t_2$, and some $0<t_1<t_2.$

My solution:
I found out that the general solution of this system is $$x(t)=\left( \begin{array}{cc} c_1e^{-t}+c_2e^{-2t}  \\
 -c_2 \epsilon e^{-2t} \end{array} \right)$$ 
But could not go anymore, so I do not know if my general solution is right or not, so I will appreciate any help with that.

Comment: Have you checked that your solution satisfies the original equation?

Comment: I think it is ..

Comment: I am thinking about taking $x(0)=(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)^T$